Newbie question: My array stops working after a certain number of items or characters
I'm completely new at this and am trying to work with Javascript to build a quote generator.
I have literally thousands of quotes that I've collected over the years and they're all in a spreadsheet sorted by topic.
I asked GPT to write some basic Javascript to choose a quote from a topic once it was selected and return a random one. The code is below (I've truncated it to show an example of the array since there are a lot of quotes in the larger list with multiple topics).
It was working well until I got to topics with multiple quotes...or maybe lengthier quotes are the problem. At some point, when I add an additional quote from the spreadsheet, the random generator stops returning any quotes from any topics.
const quotes = {

Art: [
    "Contemporary trends of thought imagine that art is a fountain, whereas it is a sponge. They have decided that art should gush forth, whereas it should absorb and become saturated. They think it can be broken down into methods of depiction, whereas it is composed of organs of perception. The proper task of art is to be always an observer, to gauge more purely than others do, more receptively and faithfully. -Boris Pasternak",
    "Art...is about rearranging us, creating surprising juxtapositions, emotional openings, startling presences, flight paths to the eternal. - Rosamund Stone Zander and Benjamin Zander"
  ],

};

// Updated getRandomQuote function to handle more topics
function getRandomQuote(topic) {
  const topicQuotes = quotes[topic];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * topicQuotes.length);
  return topicQuotes[randomIndex];
}

// Event listener for "DOMContentLoaded" and "New Quote" button (similar to previous code)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const topicSelect = document.getElementById("topic-select");
  const quoteElement = document.getElementById("quote");

  document.getElementById("new-quote-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const selectedTopic = topicSelect.value;
    const randomQuote = getRandomQuote(selectedTopic);
    quoteElement.textContent = randomQuote;
  });
});

After trial and error, I realized that there's an issue with the brackets around the overall topic: In Sublime Text Editor that I'm using, the brackets are underlined when they are working and stop being underlined when something's wrong with the code, so I've learned that when I get to a certain number of letters in the quote, it stops working (i.e. the underlined brackets in Sublime stop being underlined). And, again, when a quote and topic stop working, the entire random generator stops returning any quotes from any of the topics.
Any text (not just the offending quote) makes the bracket stop working. If go on to a different topic with new brackets after fixing the problem, it works again to a point. But then at a certain point, if I include enough quotes, it stops working halfway through the quote as though only a certain number of characters will work.
I can't find any consistent pattern with what's making it stop working.
I'm happy to share whatever might be helpful in fixing this issue.
Thanks for any help you can provide!

"I'm happy to share whatever might be helpful in fixing this issue." - a minimal snippet of code that reproduces the problem would be ideal. We call it a [mcve].

Please check the tagging of your question - it should include the programming language you're using

This is a lot of text to say your code can't handle quotes in string. Consider escaping these quotes, you could even do that with a search/replace :)

Do you get any errors in the console? Is the code breaking consistent? That is to say - happening after you add a certain quote.

The code is breaking consistently, but when I tried to create a "minimal reproducible example" it fixed the problem for that quote. So now, I'm trying different arrangements of things to see whether I can fix it.
